# Unable to talk to self-hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

Summary: 
I noticed that one of the remote machines is not able to connect to this self-hosted WCF service.

> Message: Error :System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://workflowclientservice.mmx.com/WorkflowClientService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

The other remote machines are able to talk to the self-hosted WCF service.

Background: 
I have a windows service called "Dispatcher Service" and this service is self-hosting some WCF services such as "Workflow Log Service", "Alert Service" and "Workflow Client Service"

I have another windows service called "Client Service" that is consuming these self-hosted WCF services. This windows service (Client Service) is installed on different remote machines. The client service installed on the remote machines are able to communicate to this self-hosted WCF service.

What I have already tried:
I have checked the firewalls and i don't see any issues on the client and the host.

In one of the remote machine (that is able to talk to the service), I opened up an ie browser on the machine and I was able to access the service through the website

In the problem remote machine (that is not able to talk to service), I was not able to reach the service at all in the browser.

I am trying to understand why one of the remote machine is not able to talk to this self-hosted service while other remote machines are able to talk to the service. I would like to try some steps to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does your service expose a metadata endpoint? Have you tried using WcfTestClient to talk to the self-hosted WCF service? I would try this from the same machine as the service to being with